# mysql user in time period where null exisit

Tags: mysql, timestamp

Assuming now is 2017-01-18 15:00:00

```
In                    Name            Out
2017-01-17 09:00:00   Sam             2017-01-17 11:00:00
2017-01-18 10:00:00   James           2017-01-18 12:00:00
2017-01-18 10:00:00   John            NULL          -> means still in office
```

How do I find all people who is in office between 2017-01-18 11:00:00 (start range) AND 2017-01-18 13:00:00 (end range) only for example?

**I am not sure how to handle when search start range is after 'In' time and search end range is within 'Out (NULL)' time.**

I should get James and John as the answer.

Tried this (only returns James):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE 
(In BETWEEN '2017-01-18 10:00:00' AND '2017-01-18 13:00:00' OR Out BETWEEN 2017-01-18 10:00:00' AND '2017-01-18 13:00:00') 
OR 
('2017-01-18 10:00:00' BETWEEN In AND Out OR '2017-01-18 13:00:00' BETWEEN In AND Out)
```

Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: But why is James *in*???

Comment: I search between 11:00 to 13:00.   James was in office until 12:00. So he is still in the search range

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
 WHERE '2017-01-18 10:00:00' < COALESCE(`Out`,NOW())
  AND '2017-01-18 13:00:00' >= `In`;
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [answer]. You should provide some information why your code solves the problem.
Code-only answers aren't useful for the community.

Comment: @JimHawkins I can only see the bit about sucking eggs.

Comment: thank you for teaching me a new slang. I'm not a native english speaker.

Comment: @JimHawkins You don't hear it so much these days, so it might be lost on millennials.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation of *how* and *why* this solves the problem [would really help](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Jeez, I love it when I get knocked into 'Low Quality Posts'